# If a figure with perimeter $>2n$ lies in a square with unit sides, then a line parallel to a side meets the figure in at least $n+1$ points

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> Consider a square of unit length. A figure with perimeter strictly greater than $2n$ consisting only of straight lines is drawn inside the square. Here, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The figure may or may not be self-intersecting. Prove that there always exists a line $L$ parallel to one of the sides of the square that intersects the figure in atleast $(n+1)$ points.

I have no clue how to solve this question. I've figured out the $n=1$ case. I thought induction was the way to go, but that didn't work either. Any help would be appreciated. I think for the statement to be true we need to have a square of side length $a$ such that $0<a\leq1,$ but I have no way of proving this. If we want $a>1,$ I guess we could scale up the perimeter.

Comment: It's also true if the perimeter $=2n$. Because if the sum of projection is equal to $2n$, the segments must be parallel to the sides, so we take the line it is on, will intersect at infinitely many points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider one of the line segments of the figure and project it to the $x$ or $y$ axis. The sum of the two projections is at least as long as the line segment. Hence by doing this for all line segments of the figure, the sum of all projection lengths exceeds $2n$, hence for at least one of the axes, it exceeds $n$. But when placing line segments of total length $>n$ over a line segment of length $1$, some point must be covered more than $n$ times. The line through such a point and perpendicular to the axis in question intersects the figure in more than $n$ points.

Comment: Took me a while to understand, but this is beautiful.